# React : How to show Error Message if no data is found in obj

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on react project , I am beginner to ReactJS .Actually I have implemented a logic for search filter . While searching if targeted data is not found then I want to show Error Message . I will also provide code for reference but I want to tell some logic point . I have create array as `renderData` that I am updating it with filter result . I want to make a logic if user is typing and query related data is not found in array then I want to display an error . Somebody please help me how to solve this problem . Thanks

**Code**

```
        class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep filtered data on your state or class wherever you want. For example;

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      includes: false,
    }
  }

     componentDidMount(){
           this.filtered = [];
       }

     searchHandler(event){
        if(event.target.value.toLowerCase().includes(YOUR_STRING_TO_CHECK.toLowerCase())
           { 
             this.filtered.push(event.target.value);
             this.setState({includes:true});
           }
        });
      }

   render()
     { 
        if(!this.state.includes)
        return(
        <div> ERROR</div> 
        )
        else
        return(<div> NOT ERROR </div>)
     }
```

Try something like these. Same logic. ıf you want to keep your filtered data, keep it somewhere in class.

Answer (score 1):

A nice option is:

In the  `getData()` method you could set an error in the state if the array is empty. You can check if an array is empty by using underscore.js, lodash or

```
if (array === undefined || array.length == 0) {
    // array empty or does not exist
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvoGZp

Comment: In getData() check if _.isEmpty(response.data). If true, set state in error. In your render() method check if there is any error in state and if yes, return a error page.

Comment: Actually I want to check condition in search box , if targeted value is not same with filter value . then generate message . Could you please help me out ?

Comment: Oh, I see. In my opinion a good way to do this would be making a dumb component that receives your array to render your table. If array is empty, render error. If it has items, render the items, and if the filtered array has content display the filtered content. (passing the content as props)